# Change Layout Structure in IGraph Plot based on Community

Tags: r, layout, cluster-analysis, igraph

I created an igraph with a community membership identified:

```
fc <- fastgreedy.community(graph)
colors <- rainbow(max(membership(fc)))
```

This provided me the clusters that each of the nodes belong to.

Now when I plot this:

```
plot(graph,vertex.color=colors[membership(fc)], 
    layout=layout.kamada.kawai)
```

it doesn't provide a layout where it exclusively separates each group of nodes based on the membership. Does anyone know a different layout that can provide this? All this is doing is taking the layout: kamada.kawai and coloring in the memberships rather than restructuring the layout so that it is organized by membership.

Hope this question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: What does the igraph manual suggests? I can give an advice to try out "Cytoscape". It has some very nice visual customization options for graphs.

Comment: Modify the network by adding (strong) ties between all vertices within communities, and calculate the layout on this network. Then use the calculated layout with the original network.

Comment: Let's say I create strong ties (dichotomize the matrix) so that we have it from 0-the number of clusters, do you think that if I transform the matrix into this, it will automatically reposition the network graph when I do my layout? @GaborCsardi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to calculate the Kamada-Kawai layout with an artificial weight vector that assigns a high weight to edges within clusters and a low weight to edges that cross cluster boundaries:

```
> graph <- grg.game(100, 0.2)                 # example graph
> cl <- fastgreedy.community(graph)
> weights <- ifelse(crossing(cl, graph), 1, 100)
> layout <- layout_with_kk(graph, weights=weights)
> plot(graph, layout=layout)
```

The trick here is the `ifelse(crossing(cl, graph), 1, 100)` part -- `crossing(cl, graph)` takes a clustering and the graph that the clustering belongs to, and returns a Boolean vector that defines for each edge whether the edge is crossing cluster boundaries or not. The `ifelse()` call then simply replaces `TRUE` (i.e. edge crossing boundaries) in this vector with 1 and `FALSE` (i.e. edge stays within the cluster) with 0.